# WPF: Change FontSize of ComboBox without knowing items

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, font-size

I want to set the `FontSize` for some `ComboBox`es in wpf. But the only solution I found, is to set the `FontSize` of the particular `ComboBoxItem`s. But the items are dynamically added (so I could listen on `ItemsChanged` and set the style each time, but that is very ugly).
Is there a way to set the `FontSize` for all items of a `ComboBox` generally?

**EDIT1:** The `ComboBox`es themselves are also dynamically added in code.

**EDIT2:** Following your answers it must be something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyComboBox"">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyComboItemStyle}"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MyComboItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

But it also has no effect!

**EDIT3:** Here's how I add the Items:

```
string[] strEnums = //Some dynamic magic;
foreach (string str in strEnums)
{
    (input as ComboBox).Items.Add(strEnum);
}
```

**EDIT4:** And here's the initialization of the combobox:

```
input = new ComboBox();
input.SetResourceReference(ComboBox.StyleProperty, "MyComboBox");
```

That's all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the way how all the items get rendered with defining the ItemTemplate of the ComboBox. In there you bind to the properties of the bound Items.

Example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding whateverbinding}">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content}" FontSize="12" />
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: So the Binding is not correct. Just check which property of your Objects have to be bound to the Text of the ComboBoxItem. replace "Content" in my example with the name of this property

Comment: I have no binding, I manually add strings in the code (see edits in question).

Comment: So try Text="{Binding Path=.}"

Answer (score 7):

1.If you want to set the `FontSize` for the entire `ComboBox`, you can set the `FontSize` property of the `ComboBox` itself:

```
<ComboBox FontSize="18" ...>
   ...
</ComboBox>
```

2.If you want to change the `FontSize` only on items or change the font size based on some criteria, you should specify `ItemContainerStyle':

```
<ComboBox ...>
   <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
       </Style>
   </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   ...
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Both doesn't work! The first option was of course the first thing i've tried.

Comment: @SpeziFish - Apparently this is because content of the combo box items somehow overrides the font size set on the combobox. Could you post the code for items content?

Comment: @SpeziFish - Just tried and it works perfectly. Are there any other properties you set on the text boxes that are inside combo box? Do those text boxes have the default style? Does you combo box have the default style? Could you also show the code where you create and initialize text boxes. Also you could try specifying TextBlock.FontSize="..." on your combobox.

Comment: Sorry, no textboxes, only strings (see edits), I looked at the wrong code.

Comment: @SpeziFish - Both. They do basically the same thing. Only first option sets the font size on higher level on visual tree.

Comment: Strange. I tried both, set the fontsize in code and in resource, but both has no effect. And if I change something else like background it works, only fontsize doesn't work.

Comment: @SpeziFish - You can use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the visual tree of your elements and see on which element in the path from ComboBox to TextBlock that contains your string the FontSize property gets changed.

Comment: Good idea. I even have snoop installed, but forget to use it :-)

Comment: Ok, i've found the wrongdoer. I have a general style for textboxes defined, with a certain fontsize. And this does overwrite the fontsize of my combobox. When I remove the textbox-style, the combobox-style is accepted. Very strange...